# Using C#, is there a way to retrieve all field, types, and data from a query?

Tags: c#, sql

I have multiple stored procs that I am using to retrieve various data.  These procs return different fields and I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically retrieve the fields, types and data so I can pass them into a model?

```
using (var dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(
                    dbConnectionString,
                    CommandType.Text,
                    sql,
                    sqlParams
                ))
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var Data = new Results
                        {
                            Name = (string)dr["Name"],
                            Value = (double)dr["Value"],
                            Timestamp = (DateTime)dr["DateTime"]
                        };
                        DataItems.Add(Data);
                    }
                }
```

I'm looking for a way to  change the while portion and dynamically do the while portion where the results will be set to the Results model via field, type, and data.  That way I don't have to make specific cases.  The model is setup to take all the possible results so just assume that whatever data comes back will work with the Results model.

Comment: It sounds like you are going down the road of creating a custom ORM even though you might not yet realize this. I would take a step back and check if this is really something you want to do. Have you evaluated existing frameworks like EF, NHibernate, etc? If not why? These are problems that have already been tackled, any reason to reinvent the wheel by better teams that you (no offence meant, they are better than most of us (me too) in this field after all it is what they specialize in)?

Comment: Is there really no way that is built into C# to just pass the results in the while to the model and let the model fill the fields?  Instead of listing each column type just pass in the result itself?  (i.e. var Data = new Results(dr))?

Comment: You either have to build generic mapping (tranlation) code to translate database results to model OR each model (or model factory) has to have the ability to take a DataReader or DataRow and populate itself from the database. The first 1 has been done countless of times before in various ORMs, if you want examples I suggest you find an open source one that you like and look at the source code. The 2nd is some code repeat but each model/factory is in charge of getting the appropriate field and assigning it to the corresponding property on the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataReader GetSchemaTable function to retrirving filed count and prperties, this is sample code of how to use

```
static void GetSchemaInfo(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}",
                   column.ColumnName, row[column]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for mor information you see this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This does not solve the OPs problem of mapping returned database columns/fields to an object. You would need reflection on the object being built and then mapping information between the properties on that object and the column names and finally assignment of values based on that mapping. Essentially the OP is asking to recreate that functionality of an ORM, not so much just getting the column name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you're question  correctly you need to use dynamic data to retrieve from  the database - than you could find whenever you want in the result set. As an example of such approach there is [Massive](https://github.com/FransBouma/Massive) MicroORM which allows reading result sets into dynamic variables and than read any kind of data that may exist there.